# Parsing Spanish date in C# works differently on desktop and server

Tags: c#, datetime

When attempting to parse a date with the culture `es-ES` I am getting different behavior locally than when running the same code on the build server and when using dotnetfiddle.

My test program that highlights this problem is as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var when = new DateTime(2018, 01, 19);

    CultureInfo dateCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    var headerDate = "19-ene-2018";

    bool success;
    DateTime result;

    Console.WriteLine(when.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dateCulture));

    success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
            headerDate,
            "dd-MMM-yyyy",
            dateCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
            out result);

    Console.WriteLine(success);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Locally this produces:

```
19-ene-2018
True
1/19/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

Whereas on on dotnetfiddle it produces:

```
19-ene.-2018
False
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

The first surprising thing is that using the exact same date format the server formats the month as `ene.` where as locally it is `ene` (notice the extra period). This is what I believe is causing the actual date not to parse.

Before giving up and either using a regex or some other equally horrible solution to this does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening? Is this a difference between the server and desktop framework installations?

Comment: Do try to avoid debugging a remote machine you can't change.

Comment: locally for me, the period is also required.

Comment: Have you tried with `es-US or es-VE` ?

Comment: You could try to use the `es-ES_tradnl` culture, which is mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx. On my computer this doesn't create the period. But I also don't know what other things this might change.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't explain why "es-ES" culture can have different `AbbreviatedMonthNames`. Here is an solution to it:

Depending whether the period is expected or not, you can modify `AbbreviatedMonthNames` with this:

```
CultureInfo dateCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
dateCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = dateCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames
    // uncomment one of the two lines below
    //.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('.'))
    //.Select(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.EndsWith(".") ? x : x + ".")
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that extra period is produced in dotnetfiddle specifically. But, using `CultureInfo` with the traditional sort order works perfectly  on local as well as on dotnetfiddle *(also mentioned by [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035029/dirk); `es-ES_tradnl`)*:

```
CultureInfo dateCulture = new CultureInfo(0x040A);
```